# How to connect to several AP's using a single physical wlan interface?

Tags: linux, wifi

For research purposes and concerning hardware limitations in an environment where my machine does not have more than one wifi adapter, I need to connect in several AP's at the same time to perform some tests and I cannot be dependent in physical interfaces.
The AP's may be in the same channel but it may not as well.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience there is always a big fat firmware that run on the processor on the network card , not the cpu . when we want scannning , associating , authenticating . the linux kernel driver don't generate any electromagnetic wave ( aka. radio ) but instead make calls to the network card . so unless manufacturers implement the correspongding multi-association functionality on the chips , we cannot use it . and there are no such consumer products that i know of do come with such functionality implemented .

whether this is possible on the physical layer is not clear to me .